# "Request Desktop Site" with an Intent in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, firefox, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have the ability to launch Firefox Mobile from a Forms app via an `Intent`:

```
private const string FirefoxPackage = "org.mozilla.firefox";

private void App_FirefoxUriRequested(object sender, string e)
{
    var intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetPackage(FirefoxPackage);
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(e));
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

If installed, Firefox will open a new tab with the URL passed by the `e` argument.  This works well.

In Firefox Mobile, under the Ellipsis (...) drop-down there is a checkbox for "Request Desktop Site" for the tab.  Is there a way to pass that setting somehow via the URL or `Intent`?  Maybe by somehow specifying the User Agent string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way of using intents to force the browser to launch as a desktop site.

In order to make something happen, you could add query parameters to your URL and then code the website to read the URL Query parameters (like mobile=false in www.google.com?mobile=false), so that when the server gets such a request, the server produces a desktop site.

Comment: Thanks @Saamer.  Thats too bad.  I was hoping to use something like that on ANY site and not necessarily ones we control.  Have to come up with something else.

Comment: If you load the web URL inside the app, then you can call JS code. So perhaps there’s some JS code you can call that request the desktop site for you